# why cpp codes is not getting compiled even after i installed cpp extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw

[This problem is showing when i am trying to compile my code in vs code]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Esrf.png)

I tried to solve this problem by editing json file but nothing works.

This is I am getting after compilation:

Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file

Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\akanksha yadav\Desktop\cppcodes\helloworld.cpp" -o "C:\Users\akanksha yadav\Desktop\cppcodes\helloworld.exe"
C:\Users\AKANKS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccW7k8xx.o: In function `main': C:/Users/akanksha yadav/Desktop/cppcodes/helloworld.cpp:5: undefined reference to` std::cout'
C:/Users/akanksha yadav/Desktop/cppcodes/helloworld.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' C:\Users\AKANKS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccW7k8xx.o: In function` _tcf_0':
c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' C:\Users\AKANKS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccW7k8xx.o: In function` _static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

- The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Answer (score 0):

> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file

the above is the problem. you are compiling c++ file with straight c compiler

for compiling .cpp files we use g++.exe

that's why the logs are screaming at you with errors such as `undefined reference to std::cout` . std::cout does not exist in .c files

**Solution**

1. edit your build configurations on your VSc*de so that it uses `g++.exe` instead of `gcc.exe` OR
2. Raw-dog it by typing `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe && .\helloworld.exe` on VSc*de terminal.

welcome to the world of hair-yanking! :)